# Javascript can this poker straight detection function be optimised?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking to optimise my code to get even more speed. Currently the code detects any poker hand and takes ~350ms to do 32000 iterations. The function to detect straights, however seems to be taking the biggest individual chunk of time at about 160ms so looking if any way to optimise it further.

The whole code was originally written in php since that is what I'm most familiar with but despite php 7's speed boost it still seems to be slower than javascript. What I found when translating to javascript though is that many of php's built in functions are not present in javascript which caused unforeseen slowdowns. It is still faster overall than the original php code though but I'm looking to see if it can be optimised more. Perhaps the answer is no, but I thought I'd check anyway.

I have written the functions `range` and `arrays_equal` since these are either missing from javascript or don't quite work properly.

```
function straight(handval) {
  if (arrays_equal(handval.slice(0, 4),[2, 3, 4, 5]) && handval[handval.length-1] == 14) {//if is Ace 2345
    return [4,14];
  }
  else {//if normal straight
    for (let i = handval.length - 5; i >= 0; i--) {
     let subhand = handval.slice(i, i + 5);
     if (arrays_equal(subhand, range(subhand[0], subhand[subhand.length-1]))) {
      return [4,subhand[4]];
     }
   } return [0]
  }
}

function arrays_equal(a,b) { return !!a && !!b && !(a<b || b<a); }

function range(start, end) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Handval comes in as a simple array of 5-7 elements of numbers from 2-14 representing the cards So for example it could be `[6,8,4,11,13,2]` or `[8,4,13,8,10]`.

EDIT: The function is called and sorted at the same time with this code:

```
straight(handval.slice(0).sort(sortNumber));

function sortNumber(a,b) { return a - b; }
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com can help you.

Comment: You don't need to use `!!a`, just use `a`.

Comment: I'm not playing poker that often ... What are the rules for straight, maybe the whole algorithm could be improved ...

Comment: @Vladimir Bogomolov  Thanks for telling me about that, I wasn't aware of it's existence. :)

Comment: `!(a<b || b<a)` can be simply `a.toString() == b.toString()`

Comment: Your `arrays_equal` does not work, it basically casts the arrays to strings and then to numbers. You probably want `a.length === b.length && a.every((el, i) => el === b[i])`

Comment: @Jonas Wilms A straight is checking if any 5 cards out of a hand of 5-7 are in numerical order. But the only problem is that ace can be high or low so you have to have some way to check for that.

Comment: @JonasWilms It just compares the strings, it doesn't cast them to numbers.

Comment: How about sorting the array, then count the repeating numbers from left to right, reset the count to 1 if there is a jump, then check if the sum is 5 at the end

Comment: Just wanted to say that the code does appear to work, I've tested it many times. I'm sure there are better and faster ways to do it though. Maybe if someone wants to give an answer for this?

Comment: [so] is for help with fixing code. As mentioned above, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place to ask for style advice on working code.

Comment: @Jonas Wilms Note that it's important to find the highest straight, we don't want it to return 6 as being the best straight if the cards are 2,3,4,5,6,7,8. That's why the loop goes backwards.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that's already been mentioned, like I said above, I was previously unaware of it's existence. I know it for next time anyway. :)

Comment: @barmar yet no one voted to migrate, ... so why don't we just keep it here ?

Comment: @barmar I'm wondering why you want to convert them to strings when they are arrays of numbers? Also not sure why the arrays_equal is changing the numbers to strings? I can't see where that is happening.

Comment: @hasen it turns the arrays to strings. Youncan't compare arrays with `<` or `>`, JS will cast everything to strings (or numbers) then

Comment: From your code it appears that the array is already sorted (as you compare to `range` which is sorted)

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to mention the function is called with `straight(handval.slice(0).sort(sortNumber));` I updated the question to reflect this. I always forget something..

Comment: @Hasen JS doesn't have a built-in array comparison operator, so one way is to convert them to strings and compare them.

Comment: There's a major speed boost already with the `arrays_equal` changes suggested. :) Anything else, or does anyone want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just go from right to left and count the number of sequential numbers:

```
 function straight(handval) {
   if([2, 3, 4, 5].every((el, i) => handval[i] === el) && handval[handval.length-1] === 14)
     return [4, 14];

   let count = 1;
   for(let i = handval.length - 1; i >= 1; i -= 1) {
     if(handval[i] === handval[i - 1] + 1) {
       count += 1;
       if(count === 5) return [ 4, handval[i + 3] ];
     } else {
       count = 1;
     }
   }

  return [0];
}
```

That is way faster as it:

1) does not create intermediate arrays on every iteration, which you did with `range` and `slice`

2) does not compare arrays as strings, which requires a typecast and a string comparison, which is way slower than comparing two numbers against each other

3) It does not check all 3 ranges on its own (1 - 5, 2 - 6, 3 - 7), but does all that in one run, so it only iterates 5 positions instead of 3 x 5.

Comment: You have a typo with `handval` but it won't let me edit it because I have to edit at least 6 characters?? Weird, not sure if you can edit it yourself. Also you don't have anything to check for straights with aces, I assume that can be kept as in the original code?

Comment: @hasen I'll look at it if I got time (in an hour) how does it perform?

Comment: It doesn't seem to detect a straight just yet. I assume `array` should be `handval` here right? I don't think this will work 'cos you're going backwards so `handval[i] === handval[i - 1]` will never be true. Hanval is sorted in numerical order so it's like 2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: It should be `if (handval[i] === handval[i - 1] + 1)` ?

Comment: @hasen oh right, my bad. Was in a hurry while answering, should work as expected now.

Comment: Ok it's all working great now. The array_values function was actually making the biggest hit. Fixing that with your changes above took it down from 160ms to about 20ms. But your straight code took it down even further to 10ms. The straight code function is now the fastest part of my detection code so I need to look at the other parts for further optimisation. :)

Comment: @hasen so from 350ms to 10ms?

Comment: 160ms to 10ms. 350ms is the total time to calculate any poker hand. Now it's 220ms total. The timing is not exact since every time it calculates there are so many cards that come up and result in different checks. Certainly a very significant speed boost!